# DNS doesn't update. Old ones remains active

Tags: web, dns

I have a website which I recently changed hosting. As usual in these cases, from the dns control panel the new values were updated as we said from the hosting.

The problem here is somehow the old values are still active, and the old website is shown when I type my url​​ in the browser. I've sent a request to the dig tool and this is what it brings back:

Request myweb.com with OLD NS (dns27.host.com)

```
 id 6529
 opcode QUERY
 rcode NOERROR
 flags QR AA RD
 ;QUESTION
 .myweb.com. IN NS
 ;ANSWER
myweb.com. 14400 IN NS dns27.host.net.
myweb.com. 14400 IN NS dns28.host.net.
 ;AUTHORITY
 ;ADDITIONAL
```

Request myweb.com with CORRECT NS  (dns33.host.com)

```
 id 54917
 opcode QUERY
 rcode NOERROR
 flags QR AA RD
 ;QUESTION
myweb.com. IN NS
 ;ANSWER
myweb.com. 86400 IN NS dns33.host.net.
myweb.com. 86400 IN NS dns34.host.net.
 ;AUTHORITY
 ;ADDITIONAL
```

It looks like the 2 'pairs' of dns, old and new, are active.

Now, if I request to see what A value is sent (OLD NS):

```
 id 35097
 opcode QUERY
 rcode NOERROR
 flags QR AA RD
 ;QUESTION
myweb.com. IN A
 ;ANSWER
myweb.com. 14400 IN A 111.111.111.111 --- IP OLD HOSTING (WRONG!)
 ;AUTHORITY
myweb.com. 14400 IN NS dns28.host.net.
myweb.com. 14400 IN NS dns27.host.net.
 ;ADDITIONAL
```

if I request to see what A value is sent (NEW NS):

```
 id 63164
 opcode QUERY
 rcode NOERROR
 flags QR AA RD
 ;QUESTION
myweb.com. IN A
 ;ANSWER
myweb.com. 86400 IN A 22.222.222.222 --- IP NEW HOSTING (CORRECT!)
 ;AUTHORITY
 ;ADDITIONAL
```

But nothing is returned in Authority.

The tests request have been made launching the google tool https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/
but I have tried others like DNSStuff, etc...

In the control panel I have only the right NS.

Comment: can you share the real domain name?

Comment: Sure. It's vheritagetravel.com. I've changed again the NS records from my control panel just to be sure that it takes the changes OK when i launch the dig tool, using Name and Name Server with the right dns, and they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dns33.host.net` and `dns34.host.net` look properly configured, but query will never reach them since .com TLD name servers still point to `dns27.host.net` and `dns28.host.net`:

```
;; Answer received from 192.12.94.30 (132 bytes)
;;
;; Security Level : UNCHECKED
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20896
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

OPT pseudo-record : payloadsize 4096, xrcode 0, version 0, flags 0


;; QUESTION SECTION (1  record)
;; vheritagetravel.com. IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION (2  records)
vheritagetravel.com.    172800  IN  NS  dns27.viethost.net.
vheritagetravel.com.    172800  IN  NS  dns28.viethost.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION (3  records)
dns27.viethost.net. 172800  IN  A   115.146.122.138
dns28.viethost.net. 172800  IN  A   115.146.122.138
```

You should go to your registrar's (looks like that is `PublicDomainRegistry.com`) control panel and add your new name servers there (and remove old ones of course).

Comment: you're right. Them problem was that in my registrar control panel, the old ones didn't appear. I sent a mail to them and magically it worked.